Understanding AC to DC Conversion Without a Transformer
I have a circuit designed for a hotel power switch that converts 220V AC to 12V DC. The circuit doesn’t use a traditional transformer. Instead, it uses a combination of resistors, capacitors, rectifiers, and a transistor. I’m looking to understand the working principles and specifications of this type of circuit.

How does the resistor-capacitor-rectifier combination achieve a stable 12V DC from 220V AC?
What are the key specifications for the resistors, capacitors, and rectifiers in this setup?
How does the transistor fit into the circuit, and what role does it play in voltage regulation?

I’ve attached pictures of the unassembled and assembled PCBs for reference. Any explanations or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!




From looking at the traces on the PCB around the power supply it appears to be a capacitive power supply or capacitive dropper. Pay attention to the safety warning on the linked Wikipedia page. As for the stability of the 12 V DC supply I'm not sure. To help get a answer, can you edit the question to give the parts list for the PCB? That should allow an analysis of how well the 12 V DC supply output is regulated.

Looks like a sort of shunt regulator. D1 is probably a Zener. If the capacitive dropper's output voltage is too high D1 conducts more, turning Q2 on harder, which loads the capacitive dropper's output down trough R3...

@ChesterGillon I've updated image of unassembled top pcb with values

What is a hotel power switch?

The transistor and diode may be for driving the relay from a module to which this device gives supply. It's just a "standard" capacitive dropper.

@Naeem Given the PCB is shown with a relay labelled with COIL 24VDC are you sure the supply voltage is 12 V DC rather than 24 V DC? As for the parts list, do you know what D1 is? If D1 is a Zener as suggested by @Unimportant then the part number of D1 could impact the generated supply voltage.

@winny It's a switch that requires a key card to activate the hotel room power. It's to save the hotel money, when you leave the room you take your key card with you, so you can't leave the lights or TV on wasting energy.

It's a "capacitive dropper" supply.  A capacitor has an impedance to AC.  This means that it can be used for current limiting, like a resistor.  But it has a huge advantage that the capacitor doesn't get hot doing it.
C1 will have been chosen to allow the required current through at 220V AC.  It's the key component.  Then the bridge rectifier converts that to DC, and C2 smooths the ripply DC.
The transistor will then be part of a voltage regulator.  Quite possibly using a zener diode (as suggested by Chester Gillon in the comments).
The important safety warning on any capacitive dropper supply is that the low voltage output is not isolated from the AC supply.  You can be electrocuted if you touch even the 12V side of the regulator.
